# Daedalus synch problem

Tags: daedalus, syncing

Not always, but very often the Daedalus wallet seems to synchronize completely again. Shouldn't the downloaded blockchain be permanently on the computer and then only the missing rest be synchronized?

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific use case is, and maybe you just want Daedalus, but I would recommend not using it. While being a full node, it doesn't serve much purpose for network integrity.

Answer (score 1):

yes it should be as you said. But, if not closed in the proper way, Daedalus will scan its db for corrupted chunks.

Always let Daedalus run when starting up or closing down.